# Basic Memory Model Diagram for Node Class (Java)

Tags: java, linked-list, java-memory-model

I have a question to draw the memory model diagram for the code below:
[image: Question]

With the given answer here:
[image: Answer]

My question is why is the value for next stored inside the box while the values for data (11 and 5) are pointed to outside the box. I am thinking it is because it is a null value, but what is the reason if so?

Comment: Can you copy the question and answer directly into your post? That way we won't have to click through to find it.

Comment: This question post becomes completely useless as soon as the external link does not work anymore for some reason; that's why you need to put all information directly relevant to the question into this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`5` and `11` are primitive values. Since `data` is a reference type to `E`, `data` cannot be a primitive type, so it is a reference *(hmm, I already said that)* to the object (e.g. `Integer`) holding the primitive value (e.g. `int`).

Reference types like `E` and `Node` *(bad, bad code, using a raw generic)*, can either reference an object, or be `null`. Hence `null` is that actual value of the type.

Similarly, `data` can reference an object of type `E`, or be `null` if your list allow null values.